# yaml checkout only triggering branch

Tags: azure-devops, yaml

I want to avoid fetching every single branch everytime i do a checkout in my pipeline.
I have a template which looks like this. Is there anyway for me to specify so that i only checkout out the branch that triggered the run

```
jobs:
  - job: zzz
    displayName: "yyy"
    pool:
      vmImage: 'xxx'
    steps:
      - checkout: self
        lfs: false
        fetchDepth: 0
      - task aaa
      .
      .
      .
```

This is how my template looks at the moment, and what is want is something like this (not valid syntax)

```
jobs:
  - job: zzz
    displayName: "yyy"
    pool:
      vmImage: 'xxx'
    steps:
      - checkout: self@$(Build.SourceBranch)
        lfs: false
        fetchDepth: 0
      - task aaa
      .
      .
      .
```

Is there any way to achive this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following format:[Checking out a specific ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops#checking-out-a-specific-ref) to checkout the repo with the variable.

```
- checkout: git://MyProject/MyRepo@features/tools
```

For example:

```
steps:
- checkout: git://projectname/Reponame@$(Build.SourceBranch)
  fetchDepth: 0
```

Then it will checkout the branch based on the pipeline variable:`Build.SourceBranch`

Comment: Thanks for your response,

The problem with this approach is that there is no build varibale for projectname, if multiple projects want to use the same tempalte we need to pass the projectname to this tempale as a parameter. Or am i missing something?

`
steps:
- checkout: git://projectname/$(Build.Repository.Name)@$(Build.SourceBranch)
  fetchDepth: 0
`

I would prefer to keep it more generic is possible

Comment: The command: `- checkout: Self`  will only checkout the source repo. If you only want to checkout source repo. You can hardcode the project and repo name. On the other hand, if you need the build variable for Projectname, you can use the Pipeline variable: `$(System.TeamProject)`. You can refer to the doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

Comment: Thanks, for your help. It seems that until https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2022/sprint-209-update?tabs=yaml goes live and i am able to turn of noTags the fetching will still take some extra time, but this solved one of my issues